# Subset vector string of names (based on case)

Tags: r

I would like to split a vector of names:

```
names <- c("DOE John", "VAN DYKE Dick", "SMITH Mary Jane")
```

into two vectors

```
last <- c("DOE", "VAN DYKE", "SMITH")
```

and

```
first <- c("John", "Dick", "Mary Jane")
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Can you share what you've tried so far, and why it hasn't worked as you'd like?

Comment: I've tried strplit(names, " ") which splits along the spaces.  The problem is that the length words in last names and first names is not constant. The one constant is that last names are always in all caps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
# Define a pattern that only matches words composed entirely of capital letters
pat <- paste("^[", paste(LETTERS, collapse=""), "]*$", sep="")
# [1] "^[ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ]*$"

names <- c("DOE John", "VAN DYKE Dick", "SMITH Mary Jane") 
splitNames <- strsplit(names, " ")

# LAST NAMES: (Extract and paste together words matching 'pat')
sapply(splitNames, 
       function(X) paste(grep(pat, X, value=TRUE), collapse=" "))
# [1] "DOE"      "VAN DYKE" "SMITH" 

# First Names: (Extract and paste together words NOT matching 'pat')
sapply(splitNames, 
       function(X) paste(grep(pat, X, value=TRUE, invert=TRUE), collapse=" "))
# [1] "John"      "Dick"      "Mary Jane"
```

To match all upper case letters, you could alternatively use the character class `[:upper:]`, as in:

```
pat <- "^[[:upper:]]*$"
```

although the documentation at `?regexp` seems to mildly warn against doing so, on grounds of reduced portability.

Comment: And to get the first names you could add invert=TRUE inside the grep statement.

Comment: Thanks @Dason. Good to be reminded of that. It's a lot handier than having to revert to `!grepl()` !

Answer (score 1):

Here one way:

```
l <- strsplit(names," ")
splitCaps <- function(x){
    ind <- x == toupper(x)
    list(upper = paste(x[ind],collapse = " "),
         lower = paste(x[!ind],collapse = " "))
}

> lapply(l,splitCaps)
[[1]]
[[1]]$upper
[1] "DOE"

[[1]]$lower
[1] "John"


[[2]]
[[2]]$upper
[1] "VAN DYKE"

[[2]]$lower
[1] "Dick"


[[3]]
[[3]]$upper
[1] "SMITH"

[[3]]$lower
[1] "Mary Jane"
```

Do note, though, that this has the *massive* caveat that picking out the all caps words using `toupper` will be very unreliable if you start mixing in unusual character sets, locales, symbols, etc. But for very simple ASCII type situations it should work fine.